# Inno Setup add time release to button

Tags: inno-setup

Friends
add time "Button Next or Install" to get released
on the page "Ready"

15 second 
15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4 time after the button is released to click
example

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate your question, please ? It's really difficult what you're asking for. Do you want do disable the next button and enable it after 15 seconds ? If so, when ? On the wizard page or somewhere else ? Or something else ?

Comment: TLama disable it for 15 seconds

Comment: This question is relevant to my problem, and the accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for, so I asked for the question to be reopened since it’s clear enough and pretty helpful as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no built-in timer in InnoSetup at this time, you'll need to use Windows API for this. Except that, function which will be used here needs a callback function which must be wrapped for instance by  the [`InnoCallback`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=55) used by the following script.

It shows how to disable the next button on the select directory page for 5 seconds, but you can simply change the parameter of the `DisableNextButton` function, which is the interval in seconds to value that you want as well as you can change for which page you will use it. There is also the remaining time value in the next button caption:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "InnoCallback.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
var
  Counter: Integer;
  TimerID: Integer;

type
  TTimerProc = procedure(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; 
    SysTime: DWORD);

function WrapTimerProc(Callback: TTimerProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
  external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall';    
function SetTimer(hWnd: HWND; nIDEvent, uElapse: UINT;
  lpTimerFunc: UINT): UINT; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: UINT): BOOL; 
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure OnTimerTick(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; 
  SysTime: DWORD);
begin
  Counter := Counter - 1;

  if Counter <= 0 then
  begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
    if TimerID <> 0 then 
      KillTimer(0, TimerID);
  end
  else
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext) + 
      IntToStr(Counter);
end;

procedure DisableNextButton(Timeout: Integer);
var
  TimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
  Counter := Timeout;  
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
  WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext) + 
    IntToStr(Counter);
  TimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@OnTimerTick, 4);
  TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, TimerCallback);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
    DisableNextButton(5);
end;
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perfect TLama this same
But you can put time counter with the example image
while the button is disabled

Comment: I've asked you for elaboration. You've answered *disable it for 15 seconds*, so don't be surprised :-) Well, I've updated the answer, which now shows the script which will have a remaining seconds counter (of the time before the next button is enabled) in the next button caption. I hope I got it this time...

Comment: TLama thanks for your help and patience issue "resolved".
exactly what I wanted using the google translator is very difficult thanks again

Comment: Is it possible to disable two buttons on the same page ex: [button next =  with time]  [button back= no time (only disable)] I tried to gather his two scripts but could not

Comment: Of course and it's not that hard to figure it out. That's what the `Enabled` property is for. True value of it stands for enabled state, False for disabled.