# Inno setup disable two buttons on the same page

Tags: inno-setup

Disable two buttons on the same page
I tried several ways but did not get the closer this example was not correct
[button next = with time] [button back= no time (only disable)]
help to find the error bound

```
 [Code]
 var
 Counter: Integer;
 TimerID: Integer;

 type
 TTimerProc = procedure(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR;
 SysTime: DWORD);

 function WrapTimerProc(Callback: TTimerProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
 external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall';
 function SetTimer(hWnd: HWND; nIDEvent, uElapse: UINT;
 lpTimerFunc: UINT): UINT; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
 function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: UINT): BOOL;
 external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

 procedure OnTimerTick(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR;
 SysTime: DWORD);
 begin
 Counter := Counter - 1;

 begin
 Counter := Counter - 1;
 if Counter <= 0 then
 begin
 WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True;
 WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall); 
 if TimerID <> 0 then
  KillTimer(0, TimerID);
 end
 else
 WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall) +    
   IntToStr(Counter);
 end;
 //  begin
 WizardForm.BackButton.Enabled := True;
 if TimerID <> 0 then
 begin
 if KillTimer(0, TimerID) then
   TimerID := 0;
 end;
end;

procedure DisableNextButton(Timeout: Integer);
var
TimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
Counter := Timeout;
WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall) + IntToStr(Counter);  
TimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@OnTimerTick, 4);
TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, TimerCallback);
end;

procedure DisableBackButton(Timeout: UINT); 
var
TimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
WizardForm.BackButton.Enabled := False;  
TimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@OnTimerTick, 4);
TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, Timeout, TimerCallback);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged5(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  DisableNextButton(10);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged6(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  DisableBackButton(5000);
end;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you're going to do ? You're obviously disabling both buttons, Next and Back. But I don't get the part where you're starting two timers for that at the same time. Do you want to disable both buttons and let just the Next button to have the countdown caption ?

Comment: That same TLama disable both buttons and let just the Next button to have the countdown caption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable both buttons, the next button and back button for a specified time while only next button will have the countdown timer caption, you can use the following modified script based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295259/960757):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "InnoCallback.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
var
  Counter: Integer;
  TimerID: Integer;

type
  TTimerProc = procedure(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; 
    SysTime: DWORD);

function WrapTimerProc(Callback: TTimerProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
  external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall';    
function SetTimer(hWnd: HWND; nIDEvent, uElapse: UINT;
  lpTimerFunc: UINT): UINT; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: UINT): BOOL; 
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure OnTimerTick(Wnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; TimerID: UINT_PTR; 
  SysTime: DWORD);
begin
  Counter := Counter - 1;

  if Counter <= 0 then
  begin
    WizardForm.BackButton.Enabled := True;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext);
    if TimerID <> 0 then 
      KillTimer(0, TimerID);
  end
  else
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext) + 
      IntToStr(Counter);
end;

procedure DisableNavigateButtons(Timeout: Integer);
var
  TimerCallback: LongWord;
begin
  Counter := Timeout;
  WizardForm.BackButton.Enabled := False;
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
  WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonNext) + 
    IntToStr(Counter);
  TimerCallback := WrapTimerProc(@OnTimerTick, 4);
  TimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, TimerCallback);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
    DisableNavigateButtons(5);
end;
```